# Returning a function in a list, from a function

Tags: function, r

I searched for this question, but found answers that weren't specific enough.

I'm cleaning up old code and I'm trying to make sure that the following is relatively clean, and hoping that it won't bite me on the rear later on.

My question is about passing a function through a function.  Look at the "y" part of the following plot statement.   The `goo(df)[[1]](x)` thing works, but am I asking for trouble in any way?   If so, is there a cleaner way?

Also, if the `goo()` function is called many many times, for instance in a Monte Carlo analysis, will this load up R's internals or possibly cause some type of environment issues?

Edit (02/21/2011) --- The following code is just an example.  The real function "goo" has a lot of code before it gets to the approxfun() statement.

```
#Build a dataframe
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), b=c(4, 3, 1, 2, 6))

#Build a function that passes a function
goo <- function(inp.df) {
  out.fun <- approxfun(x=inp.df$a, y=inp.df$b, yright=max(inp.df$b), method="linear", f=1)
  list(out.fun, inp.df$a[5], inp.df$b[5])
}

#Set up the plot range
x <- seq(1, 4.3, 0.01)

#Plot the function
plot(x, goo(df)[[1]](x), type="l", xlim=c(0, goo(df)[[2]]), ylim=c(0, goo(df)[[3]]), lwd=2, col="red")
grid()



goo(df)

[[1]]
function (v) 
.C("R_approxfun", as.double(x), as.double(y), as.integer(n), 
    xout = as.double(v), as.integer(length(v)), as.integer(method), 
    as.double(yleft), as.double(yright), as.double(f), NAOK = TRUE, 
    PACKAGE = "stats")$xout
<environment: 0219d56c>

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

Comment: This is how functions are included in `glm` objects. eg, `glmdl$family$linkinv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be better in a big Monte Carlo simulation, but for simpler situations, it might be clearer to include the x and y ranges as attributes of the output from the created function instead of in a list with the created function.  This way `goo` is a more straightforward factory, like Davor mentions.  You could also make the result from your function an object (here using S3) so that it can be plotted more simply.

```
goo <- function(inp.df) {
  out.fun <- approxfun(x=inp.df$a, y=inp.df$b, yright=max(inp.df$b), 
                       method="linear", f=1)
  xmax <- inp.df$a[5]
  ymax <- inp.df$b[5]
  function(...) {
    structure(data.frame(x=x, y = out.fun(...)), 
              limits=list(x=xmax, y=ymax), 
              class=c("goo","data.frame"))
   }
}

plot.goo <- function(x, xlab="x", ylab="approx",  
                     xlim=c(0, attr(x, "limits")$x), 
                     ylim=c(0, attr(x, "limits")$y), 
                     lwd=2, col="red", ...) {
  plot(x$x, x$y, type="l", xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, 
       xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, lwd=lwd, col=col, ...)
}
```

Then to make the function for a data frame, you'd do:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), b=c(4, 3, 1, 2, 6))
goodf <- goo(df)
```

And to use it on a vector, you'd do:

```
x <- seq(1, 4.3, 0.01) 
goodfx <- goodf(x)
plot(goodfx)
```

Comment: I've been playing around with your solution. It initially eats up more memory and the function generation may (or may not) run a little slower...we'll see, but it allows me to offload some of the complexity into how the results are used (similar to your plot.goo() function). Also, setting the class to both "goo" and "data.frame" really makes this clean. And, if I expand the class, it might help in managing the final pile of functions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to give you specific recommendations without knowing exactly what your code is, but here are a few things to consider:

1. Is it really necessary to include pieces of `goo`'s input data in its return value? In other words, can you make `goo` a straightforward factory that just returns a function? In your example, at least, the `plot` function already has all the data it needs to determine the limits.
2. If this is not possible, then stay with this pattern, but give the elements of `goo`'s return value descriptive names so that at least it's easy to see what's going on when you reference them. (E.g., `goo(df)$approx(x)`.) If this structure is used widely in your code, consider making it an S3 class.
3. Finally, don't invoke `goo(df)` multiple times in the plot function, just to get different elements out. When you do that, you literally call `goo` every time, which as you said will execute a lot of code. Also, each invocation will have its own environment with a copy of the input data (although R will be smart enough to reduce the copying to a certain extent and use the same physical instance of `df`.) Instead, call `goo` once, assign its value to a variable, and reference that variable subsequently.

Comment: Item 1, this was an example that I shortened to focus on passing/calling the function.  Both the function and the other returned values are the result of a lot of internal calcs.  Item 2, If I use goo(df)$approx(x) versus the above, will it slow things down, or improve/worsen environment issues?  Item 3, I agree. Actually that's why the real "goo" is built to provide a function/parameters, so that building the function/parameters happens less often.  During an MC run, the functions/parameters are simply used many times rather than rebuilt many times.

Comment: @bill Using `goo(df)$approx(x)` instead `goo(df)[[1]]` is likely slower because R will need to do a hash lookup instead a positional access, but I'd guess the difference is negligible and well worth the readability. I also like Aaron's suggestion to return a function and attach any other data its callers will need as attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I would remove a level of function handling and keep the input data out of the function generation. Then you can keep your function out of the goo and call approxfun only once.

It also generalizes to an input dataframe of any size, not just one with 5 rows.

```
#Build a dataframe
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), b=c(4, 3, 1, 2, 6))

#Build a function
fun <- approxfun(x = df$a, y = df$b, yright=max(df$b), method="linear", f = 1)

#Set up the plot range
x <- seq(1, 4.3, 0.01)

#Plot the function
plot(x, fun(x), type="l", xlim=c(0, max(df$a)), ylim=c(0, max(df$b)), lwd=2, col="red")
```

That might not be quite what you need ultimately, but it does remove a level of complexity and gives a cleaner starting point.

Comment: My example was just an example.  In the real thing, there's a lot of code in function goo() before the approxfun().   Dropping down a level is not an option.

Comment: Ok, that would have been useful information to start with. If your real goo() really gets called a lot, and runs approxfun only once for each little data set then you might as well use approx and just pass the estimated data around. If it really gets called many times for the same data you probably need to rethink why. There's not enough context here IMO.

Comment: It's probably not easy to see, but if I supply the internals of goo, it takes the focus away from what I'm worried about.  Function "goo" takes in a lot of data and builds a function and parameters that will be used many many times.   "goo" will be called again and again to populate a lot of functions/parameters.  All of those functions/parameters will be called according to the MC's requirements to estimate various properties of "the system".  I'm currently tracking memory usage, but I'm worried that when I scale this up, there might be some environment/syntax issue that bites me.

Comment: Out of room in the above comment, so.....As you can imagine, after "goo" has generated a lot of different functions/parameters, I have to manage that pile.   That brings up some additional problems that I haven't asked yet.